# Accessing nested firebase values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I've got something like

```
Person
   9283094823904
        username: bob
        password : wat
```

you can just use an observer for .Value and print the snapshot.value to get everything.

But if I've got something like

```
Person
       092830948290384
           username: Bob
           password: wat
           favoriteColors
                  blue: "true"
                  green: "true"
```

Why is it that if I have access to the person's UID and do a reference like

```
refPerson.child(092830948290384).child("favoriteColors").observeEventType(.Value)bhalbhlahb
```

the value returns as null?

```
print(snapshot) returns Snap (favoriteColors) <null>
```

and

```
snap.value is straight up null.
```

I don't understand why if I have the direct route to favoriteColors why .Value doesn't work the same as it does one tier back up.

I know the advice is to prevent this kind of nesting, but is there not a way to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening for

```
refPerson.child(092830948290384).observeEventType(.Value)
```

And use:

```
snapshot.value!["favoriteColors"]
```

to get the data you need into a dictionary